# What's "Code substitution (OAuth Login)" threat?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

From the [**OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations** draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-threatmodel-08#section-4.4.1.13):

> **4.4.1.13.  Threat: Code substitution (OAuth Login)**
>
> An attacker could attempt to login to an application or web site
> using a victim's identity.  Applications relying on identity data
> provided by an OAuth protected service API to login users are
> vulnerable to this threat.  This pattern can be found in so-called
> "social login" scenarios.
>
> As a pre-requisite, a resource server offers an API to obtain
> personal information about a user which could be interpreted as
> having obtained a user identity.  In this sense the client is
> treating the resource server API as an "identity" API.  A client
> utilizes OAuth to obtain an access token for the identity API.  It
> then queries the identity API for an identifier and uses it to look
> up its internal user account data (login).  The client asssumes that
> because it was able to obtain information about the user, that the
> user has been authenticated.
>
> If the client uses the grant type "code", the attacker needs to
> gather a valid authorization code of the respective victim from the
> same identity provider used by the target client application.  The
> attacker tricks the victim into login into a malicious app (which may
> appear to be legitimate to the Identity Provider) using the same
> identity provider as the target application.  This results in the
> Identity Provider's authorization server issuing an authorization
> code for the respective identity API.  The malicious app then sends
> this code to the attacker, which in turn triggers a login process
> within the target application.  The attacker now manipulates the
> authorization response and substitutes their code (bound to their
> identity) for the victim's code.  This code is then exchanged by the
> client for an access token, which in turn is accepted by the identity
> API since the audience, with respect to the resource server, is
> correct.  But since the identifier returned by the identity API is
> determined by the identity in the access token (issued based on the
> victim's code), the attacker is logged into the target application
> under the victim's identity.
>
> Impact: the attacker gains access to an application and user-specific
> data within the application.
>
> Countermeasures:
>
> - All clients must indicate their client id with every request to
>   exchange an authorization code for an access token.  The
>   authorization server must validate whether the particular
>   authorization code has been issued to the particular client.  If
>   possible, the client shall be authenticated beforehand.
> - Clients should use appropriate protocol, such as OpenID (cf.
>   [openid]) or SAML (cf. [OASIS.sstc-saml-bindings-1.1]) to
>   implement user login.  Both support audience restrictions on
>   clients.

This is rather confusing to me: «the attacker needs to gather a valid authorization code of the respective victim from the same identity provider used by the target client application». What's "the respective victim" and what does "identity provider" mean in this and subsequent uses?

The whole attack description is obscure. I came to understand it as "one shouldn't use OAuth 2.0 to implement user login", but wouldn't that mean that major platforms such as Facebook are vulnerable? And vulnerable to what, exactly?

I probably only need a clarification of some of the terms used in this paragraph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The wording in this section is a bit confusing, but the attack is quite simple. "Identity provider" is the name for the resource server used to verify the identity of an user.

Basically it's a case of using an authentication code issued for a client application to obtain an access token by a different application. I try to outline the steps in a clearer way.

1. Attacker registers a malicious client (e.g. an app registered to Facebook).
2. Victim user is tricked into logging into the malicious client using a "Login with third party" button (e.g. "Login into Facebook") triggering OAuth 2.0 authorization_code flow.
3. The malicious client gets the authorization_code.
4. The attacker uses the just obtained authorization_code with another app and obtains access to that app as the victim user.

Step 4 is only possible if authorization_codes aren't bound to a specific client. Auth codes issued to a client can only be used by that same client to obtain an access token.

Of course Facebook is not vulnerable, as this requires only a basic check from the authorization server to defeat.