# Can't code substitution happen in Hybrid Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am trying to understand openid connect code flows.

In authorization code flow, the authorization code comes through front channel. And then id_token/access_token through the back channel using client id and client credentials. Also, it is prone to Code Substitution attack and may allow hacker to impersonate the user as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957775/whats-code-substitution-oauth-login-threat)

But I am not able to understand how hybrid flow prevents this. I read [here](https://openid.net/2016/07/16/preventing-mix-up-attacks-with-openid-connect/). But what prevents hacker from replacing both code and id_token? May be i am not able to read through lines. But please help me understand this.

**Update**

After reading through a bit more, I believe id_token has information about **aud** that is to which client it was originally issued. So malicious client would have it's **aud** in that(And malicious client can't replace that with Client_Id of the origninal client as it is signed by issuer) So, the original client would be able to verify if this was issued to it or not. Is this correct understanding? Also, is there some other scenario where hacker might be able to replace both code and id_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the fact that the token is signed by the issuer and contains an `aud` claim that the Client must check will prevent swapping with tokens that are for a different Client.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. So, this scenario will work correctly. But what another ways a hacker may be able to steal both code and id_token from the original client.